# Select specific value in one column and get n rows before/after from another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns: trialType and diameter. I need to find everywhere where trialType == 'start', and then get the diameter for all 2500 rows before and after those locations, inclusive. I tried the following:

```
idx = df.loc(df[df['trialType']=='start'])
df.iloc[idx - 2500 : idx + 2500]
```

My goal is to have a dataframe with only those relevant rows (2500 rows in between each 'start' trial). Below is an example just with much fewer rows:

```
trialType diameter
start     3.15
          3.17
          3.18
start     3.14
          3.13
          3.13
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting.

What about:

```
idx = df.loc[lambda x: x['trialType']=='start'].index

rows = df.loc[idx]

a = df.shift( 2500).loc[idx]
b = df.shift(-2500).loc[idx]
```

You can then combine them however you find best.

```
pd.concat([a,rows,b])
```

---

You could also do:

```
idx = df.loc[lambda x: x['trialType']=='start'].index
df.loc[lambda x: (x.index-2500).isin(idx) 
               ¦  x.index.isin(idx) 
               ¦ (x.index+2500).isin(idx)]
```

But you have to modify the code above if your index is not sequential (0,1,2,3,etc.)

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been more specific. I'm trying to get all the rows from the 'start' to 2500 before and after, inclusive. Is there a way I can modify your code to achieve this?

Comment: Hi @KateP - do you have only one start value or multiple? If you have only one then your starting code should work. Could you edit your question with an illustrative example of what you are looking for?

Comment: Sure just edited. There are multiple start values. I did notice the code works great for one value- just not sure how to grab all of  them.

Comment: @MYK I love the simplicity of this answer so much!

Answer (score 0):

I will only change the first line to

```
idx = df.index[df['trialType']=="start"].tolist()[0]
```

this will return the first index where the condition is true

the line 2 should work fine `df.iloc[idx - 2500 : idx + 2500]`

you can run this code to try

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'team': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'Z', 'C', 'C', 'D'],
                   'points': [5, 7, 7, 9, 12, 9, 9, 4],
                   'rebounds': [11, 8, 10, 6, 6, 5, 9, 12]})
df
```

```
idx = df.index[df['team']=="B"].tolist()[0]
df.iloc[idx - 2 : idx + 2]
```

output

```
    team    points  rebounds
1   A         7          8
2   A         7          10
3   B         9          6
4   Z         12         6
```